# Android ==> Which layout should i use?

Tags: android, layout

I want o be able to add items to my layout, and set the exact position of these items.
x,y,width,height.
I am currently using AbsoluteLaout which is deprecated, is there any other layout that allows me to locate objects on the screen, by specifying their x,y?
I also need to be able to read the x,y of all these objects on the screen.
I already use getLeft(), and getTop().

Comment: Did you consider using Grid view.? what is the type of item , are they just views.?

Comment: buttons, images, textviews, etc, i also animate my views a lot, so i need to specify for example button 1 goes from position 10,15 to where my button2 is placed on the screen.
I don't understand why they would deprecate the most useful layout

Comment: Its the least useful layout, as it can't adapt to various devices, orientations, or screen sizes.

Comment: So do u have any other suggestions, on what layout i should use to be able to specify x,y,width,height of every single object on the screen?

Comment: No, and that's because you shouldn't be specifying the x, y, width, height of the items on the screen.  Think about it this way, let's say you target an mdpi device like the G1 and you layout the whole app pixel-perfect.  Well, if someone runs it on a Droid the layout will only use a part of the screen and look really bad.  What's worse is what if the person uses a Motorola Twist, which is ldpi, that means parts of your app are going to be outside of the screen and therefore unusable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RelativeLayout and set [margins](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) to position. This is going to kill various screen size compatibility.